# Как в _form.php записать произвольное значение?

Tags: yii2

Есть форма _form.php, в ней всякие поля:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
....
<?= $form->field($model, 'create_by')->textInput() ?>
....
// Тут нужно сохранить дату модификации
<?php $model->modified_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

мне нужно сохранить дату модификации в поле modified_time, почему она не сохраняется?

Answer (score 1):

Перенесите строку

```
$model->modified_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

в контроллер, где вы принимаете эту форму.

Comment: пробовал, не помогло

Comment: выкладывайте код контроллера. сохраняется ли модель вообще?